# React Router (v.4) dynamic routing problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I use HashRouter for github pages.

```js
// section is simple component like a
<Section>
  {array}
</Section>

<Route exact path={'/:pageId'} render={()=> <Section/>}/>
```

But this `{array}` is dynamic. It is updated when clicks on `<Link/>`, and if I click on `<Link/>`, routing will work. But this does not work if you change the path in the address bar. How do I update `{array}` in this case? Maybe I did the wrong task initially.
I have a main array, and a second array that copies from N to 9 elements from the main array, where N is the current page. The variable N is in store, and i think is wrong. I need to do dynamic pagination.

Comment: how and where are you updating your array?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz in another component `<CreateBox/>` with `dispatch({type: UDPATE_CURRENT_ARRAY}, payload: payload_with_array_item(pseudo code))`

Comment: What is the url you typed in the address bar ?

Comment: @Darkilen http://localhost:3000/#/page/1 or http://localhost:3000/#/page/2 etc.